# Using a UISlider to track the duration played of a soundfile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I play a sound file:

```
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/recordTest.caf", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
[audioPlayer play];

sliderUpdater = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(sliderUpdateTimer)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
```

So the sound plays, and i start the NSTimer calling my method sliderUpdateTimer.

So the method is

```
- (void) sliderUpdateTimer
{                
NSLog(@"Dur: %f",audioPlayer.duration );
NSLog(@"Cur: %f",audioPlayer.currentTime );    
[seekSlider setValue:100 * (audioPlayer.duration) / (audioPlayer.currentTime)];
}
```

Duration and currentTime both appear to be 0.

What part of this am I doing wrong?

audioPlayer.duration and currentTime return a NSTimerInterval which i believe is a double.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: I could never get the stupid slider to work either, I tried using it in a game and the thing would never update correctly. I ended up using  a -(void) draw function to make my own progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

These combinations worked fine for me,

```
-(IBAction)playAction
{
    paused = NO;
    [audioPlayer play];
    audioSlider.maximumValue = [audioPlayer duration];
    audioSlider.value = 0.0;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    audioSlider.value = audioPlayer.currentTime;
    audioTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", audioSlider.value];
}
```